# Convert a text from JavaScript into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, string

I'm trying to get a text from a JSON file parce and displaying this text as an HTML object. But I read it as a string instead.

I have a JSON file as follows:

JSON code (json/json_data.json):

```
{
    "counters": [
        {
            "variable": ":='webdata'.counter1:"
        },
        {
            "variable": ":='webdata'.counter2:"
        }
    ]
}
```

jQuery code (my_script.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON("json/json_data.json", function(result){
        $('#counter0').text(result.counters[0].variable);
    });
},1000);
});
```

HTML code (index.htm):

```
<tr>
    <td>PT000</td>
    <td>Process value 0</td>
    <td> <label id="counter0">0</label> </td>
    <td>bar</td>
</tr>
```

Now the point is that I'm getting the text written in the JSON printed on the screen, this is the name of my variable, we can say is the path to reach the value I want to print.

On the other hand, if I use an HTML file and write on it the name of the variable and then I simply use jQuery to get the data it works, but I have plenty of values I want to print out, so I thought that JSON could help me to manage this issue. Here the example with the HTML file:

HTML code (IOValue1.htm):

```
:="webdata".counter1:
```

jQuery code (my_script.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("IOValue1.htm", function(result){
        $('#counter1').text((result));
    });
},1000);
});
```

HTML code (index.htm):

```
<tr>
    <td>PT001</td>
    <td>Process value 1</td>
    <td> <label id="counter1">0</label> </td>
    <td>bar</td>
</tr>
```

Probably I'm not considering how JavaScript is treating the string that I get from the JSON file. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Have a look at Knockout.JS it is a HTML data binding framework

Comment: I also highly recommend using Knockoutjs, just like @No1_Melman said. It is easy to learn and has a great documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
$('#counter0').text(result.counters[0].variable);
```

to

```
var tmpArray = result["counters"];

var counterObject = tmpArray[0];

var variableValue = counterObject["variable"]; 

$('#counter0').text(variableValue);
```

Comment: Thanks Hamed! Eventhough the result is the same. The brouser shows the text stored in the JSON file, but not what the HTML should interpret from this text.